# Translating "facts" as "hechos" or "información"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Various online translations of this seem to miss the meaning, at least to me.

> "Why not, if you are so sure of your facts?"

Translation:

> ¿Por qué no, si estás tan segura de tus **hechos**?

I think a better translation would be to use información in place of hechos, e.g.

> ¿Por qué no, si estás tan seguro de tu información?

If I were to use this with say, native speakers in Mexico, would I get the same meaning across?

If I were translating this into English,

> ¿Por qué no, si estás tan segura de tus hechos?

I would probably translate this as:

> Why not, if you're so sure of your actions?

However, the original phrase is more about one's information or data than what one is doing.

Comment: *traduttore* = *traditore*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the right translation would be:

> Por qué no, si estás tan seguro de tus afirmaciones

- *si estás tan segura de tus hechos* means something the person **did** (hechos) but maybe they didn't do anything.
- *si estás tan seguro de tu información*, *información* means something the person got via an external way
- *si estás tan seguro de tus afirmaciones*, *afirmaciones* means something the person thinks about it, a personal opinion